# What reasonable steps can I take to report misbehavior by publishers to the wider research community?

Tags: disreputable-publishers

What resources are available for reporting unethical practices or [misbehavior](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13489/what-to-do-when-a-journal-publishes-a-paper-plagiarizing-ones-work-but-doesnt?rq=1) by publishers? I'm aware of [Beall's list](http://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/), are there other efforts to objectively identify publishers with low standards or other practices that are detrimental to the research community?

Is it helpful to submit info to organizations like [COPE](http://publicationethics.org/)?

This [meta discussion](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1297/should-we-name-names-when-talking-about-bad-publishers-and-researchers) is of interest and might suggest that AcademiaSE is not a suitable venue for sharing information on specific practices.

Comment: Beall's list is the only one I know of, and it has some serious issues (primarily, that it focuses only on Open Access while ignoring disreputable publishers with more traditional models).  It would definitely be a useful resource to have!  The problem is, how to differentiate between real complaints and people with an axe to grind (try Googling for conspiracies theories about pretty much any reputable publisher).

Answer (score 3):

If the matter concerns a mathematical journal, you can submit your case to the [European Mathematical Society ethics committee](http://www.euro-math-soc.eu/committee/ethics)

Note that even if this committee has been established by the EMS, they should consider non-European issues as well as issues from European publisher, journals and authors.

Of course, their power is somewhat limited but given their status, they could have some impact by simply issuing a public statement.